How to get sysfs full path information from show and store handler functions in kernel?
I am working with a platform driver for a clock chip. The probe function is called with a pointer to struct platform_device and the device pointer is received as
struct device *dev = &pdev->dev;
from which a pointer to struct clk is derived using the DTB entry "txref-clk"
struct clk *pclk = devm_clk_get(dev, "txref-clk");

Then I have a sysfs folder enumerated based on DTB entries of this device:
/sys/bus/platform/drivers/aw3423/amba_pl@0:hdmi0_clock/
/sys/bus/platform/drivers/aw3423/amba_pl@0:hdmi1_clock/
/sys/bus/platform/drivers/aw3423/amba_pl@0:hdmi2_clock/
/sys/bus/platform/drivers/aw3423/amba_pl@0:hdmi3_clock/

After I added additional nested sysfs groups, I now have these paths:
/sys/bus/platform/drivers/aw3423/amba_pl@0:hdmi0_clock/clk_adj/step_idx
/sys/bus/platform/drivers/aw3423/amba_pl@0:hdmi1_clock/clk_adj/step_idx
/sys/bus/platform/drivers/aw3423/amba_pl@0:hdmi2_clock/clk_adj/step_idx
/sys/bus/platform/drivers/aw3423/amba_pl@0:hdmi3_clock/clk_adj/step_idx

So from within step_idx_store, step_idx_show functions, how can I get the hdmi indices (0,1,2,3)?
because the sysfs creates these groups in each of the sysfs folders, I am sure the struct clk pointer or the device pointers are already enumerated, I just don't know what filed within them I could consult to get the enumeration.
Note that the groups that I added have the same name, not with a suffix - I was thinking adding a suffix and then retrieve the enumeration that way but I think if I can just get the indices from base path, it will be better.
Update: The line  dev_dbg(dev, "step_idx_show: channel: %d, step_size: %d)", channel, step_size);
shows his:
aw3423-init amba_pl@0:hdmi0_clock: step_idx_show: channel: 0, step_size: 45
The debug prints prbably printing an element of struct device, which means I should get the index of hdmi clock from dev structure. Anybody know what exactly gets printed from within dev_dbg ?
